# executeQuery never returns in NetBeans IDE but works when run by java

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, jdbc, ide

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 and was just testing a Microsoft SQL Server connection using JDBC from Microsoft.  I have this test program:

```
package testsql;
import java.sql.*;
public class TestSQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionURL = 
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://foo.bar.com:1433;" +
                    "databaseName=flintstone;integratedSecurity=true;";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            String SQL = con.nativeSQL("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM fred");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Count = " + rs.getString("Count"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

I have the NetBeans VM Options property set to `-Djava.library.path=C:\lib`.

When I run the code in the IDE the program freezes at executeQuery and runs 'forever'.  No error is returned and a time-out is not raised.

However if I build the package and then run it with `java -Djava.library.path=C:\lib -jar TestSQL.jar` I get the expected data returned: `Count = 7349`.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Also you could keep a System.out.println() methods before and after your call to be certain that it's indeed hanging there.

Comment: Yes I checked logs and used println() here, there and everywhere before I posted this question which is how I confirmed that it was the executeQuery() call that was freezing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the project working in the IDE now.  It turned out to be the version of the JDK I was using.  Replacing JDK1.6 with JDK1.7 fixed the problem, it works as expected now.

Comment: Most likely your JDK 1.6 was version 1.6 update 29 which had a bug which made connections to SQL Server freeze (JDK 1.7 Update 1 or 2 had the same issue btw).

Comment: Mark, you are quite correct.  It was version 1.6 update 29.  I am now on version 1.7 update 6.